# Specialization of pure virtual base method in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, pure-virtual

I wondered if there is a common way/pattern to let a derived class have a somewhat more specialized version of a pure virtual method in the given base class.

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() = default;
    virtual ~Base() = 0;
    virtual void foo(int bar) = 0;
};
inline Base::~Base() {}

class Derived public Base {
public:
    Derived() = default;
    ~Derived() = default;
    void foo(int bar) override {/*...*/}
};

class SpecializedDerived : public Base {
public:
    SpecializedDerived() = default;
    ~SpecializedDerived() = default;
    void foo(int bar, double additionalParameter) override {/*...*/}
};
```

The override in the `SpecializedDerived` class is impossible, because the signature of the method does not correspond to the one in the pure virtual `Base` class.

Now, is there a way to achieve the described design? Is there a way to implement "more specialized methods" as there is class inheritance which will allow you to implement "more specialized classes"?

While typing I reckoned that my wish is more a kind of "Dude, I just want you to provide an `iterate(.)` function of some sort!" thing.

The only idea that came to my mind so far is something like

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() = default;
    virtual ~Base() = 0;
    virtual void foo(int bar) = 0;
};
inline Base::~Base() {}

class SpecializedDerived : public Base {
public:
    SpecializedDerived(double addParam) : additionalParam_(addParam) {}
    ~SpecializedDerived() = default;
    void foo(int bar) override {
        iterate(bar, additionalParam_);
        return;
    }
private:
    double additionalParam_;
    void foo(int bar, double additionalParam) {/*...*/}
};
```

Where this internal function call is actually redundant as you could just do:

```
class SpecializedDerived : public Base {
public:
    SpecializedDerived(double addParam) : additionalParam_(addParam) {}
    ~SpecializedDerived() = default;
    void foo(int bar) override {/* code using additionalPara_ */}
private:
    double additionalParam_;
};
```

Comment: How would code that only sees a `Base*` or `Base&` is gonna call the "more specialized" method? How is it gonna pass that extra parameter?

Comment: What's wrong with your solution?

Comment: Technically you can use `virtual void foo(int bar, double additionalParameter) = 0` in the `Base` and `void foo(int bar, double additionalParameter = 0) override` in the `Derived`.

Comment: I don't understand your use case. If there should be an extra parameter, why isn't there one in `Base`?

Comment: @StoryTeller: You're completely right... a very blatant reason why something like this can't be achieved in the case of `Base* b = new SpecializedDerived();`
---
@Christian Hackl: Now that you're asking... nothing really, actually. I just don't really want the additional parameters to be members of the class.
---
@PasserBy: In this case for instance it is about an abstract base class `Iterable` that is used to calculate simulation steps. The more specialized an `Iterable` class is, the more parameters it might need and I want to "force" the user to install some kind of `iterate(.)` method.

Comment: You can't direct one comment at three people. Only the first being @mentioned is notified.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Thanks for that hint - will mind it in the future. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why is a matchnig signature necessary ?

The idea behind polymorphism and virtual functions, is that the caller doesn't have to know any details about the real class of the object it uses:

Example:

```
Base *my_object = find_dynamically_a_relevant_object (...);              
my_object->foo(10);   // could be a Derived or a SpecializedDerived

std::vector<Base*> container;  
...                   // somehow you populate the container with a mix of 
...                   // Derived AND SpecializedDerived objects 
for (auto x: container)
    x->foo(std::srand());
```

This is why the signature must match exactly the one defined in the base class.

#### But can a different signature also be used ?

Now you could very well define an overloaded `foo()` with a completely different signature under three conditions:

- It would **not** be an `override`: it's a different function with the same name.  * You could invoke the overloaded foo() with its additional parameters only if you're sure that the object has the right type.
- You would have to make sure that an override is provided with the matching signature is provided (because it is a pure virtual).  This could for example just invoke your overload, using some arbitrary values for the extra parameters)

Example:

```
class SpecializedDerived : public Base {
public:
    SpecializedDerived() = default;
    ~SpecializedDerived() = default;
    void foo(int bar) override { foo(bar, 0.0); }
    void foo(int bar, double additionalParameter)  {cout<<"specialized "<<bar<<" "<<additionalParameter<<endl;}
};

... // elsewhere, for example in main(): 

SpecializedDerived my_obj;  
my_obj.foo(10);  // use the override of the base
my_obj.foo(10, 37.2); // use the overload

// suppose that p is a Base* like in the first example
auto *q = dynamic_cast<SpecializedDerived*>(p); 
if (q)  // dynamic cast makes this nullptr if not the right type
    q->foo(10, 37.2); 
else cout << "Not specialized"<<endl;
```

#### Override with a behavior depending on some adiditional data

Now if you want to use your foo() in strictly polymorphic context but still have some (hidden) additional parameters, there are several possibilities, such as for example:

- you could extend the base signature and add an additional, mostly unused parameter with a default value. This is a bad idea in most cases: what if a new derived class comes with yet another parameter.
- you could inject the additional parameter before doing the call (either at construction as you have yourself suggested, or using a setter to change the value whenever you need).  Works most of the cases.  The only risk is to make sure that the additional parameter was set correctly before calling `foo()`
- you could change the signature to use as single parameter an object that holds all the real parameters.  This requires some extra overhead, but is extremely flexible with variable parameters.  The only thing is that the type of this object may very well need to be polymorphic as well, in which case you must be sure that the right parameter type is used for the right object.  Tis appears to me super-powerful but super-super-risky.

Comment: Thanks for this really interesting answer with all these ideas of how to do it!
About the last idea, the polymorphic parameter data class, I have also thought, but I didn't like the idea, because the method signature (being the same for all derived classes) doesn't show which specialized parameter class should be used to call it. Can you think of a solution for that problem? Just from the top of my head, one could make the pure virtual method `protected` and call it by a `public` method overload which demands the correct parameter sub class. But then again we've got method hiding in our way

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. If you have different parameter for different derived classes, then you're no longer in a polymorphic spirit. So whatever you'll do, you'll have to worry about the match parameters/real type. Personally, I'd try to design polymorphic without parameter variations.  If not possible, opt for the second bullet, and with overridden foo() to call the non-polymorphic variant with the injected parameter. Then you could make polymorphic call if needed (and with some extra gymnastics), but I would call the real method with direct parameters whenever object is of known type.

Comment: What I proposed in the previous comment is not possible due to the method hiding, right?

Comment: @LCsa making the virtual protected doesn't change the situation. It only changes what you can do directly with a class. For any overload or specific parameter, the pb is that you won't see them for a base class poibter, so that you'n have to determine the type and use the specifi members case by case

Comment: Ah, sh*t, I just wrote some [example code](https://onlinegdb.com/BkSYTucPm) on compile online to put the third bullet into practice, when I just now realized that it destroys the great advantage of being able to go through a list of parent/child objects and call the virtual foo funcition... >.> But maybe it shows you what I wanted to try with making the actual method protected, forcing the programmer to ensure a call with the correct parameter object.

Answer (score 1):

Start with reading on [Wikipedia+ contravariance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)). The idea is that the child may override a function with one that accepts a broader interface. The function must accept the old interface, but it can also extend it. The idea is not to break the expectations of code that has a reference/pointer to the base class.

Note that currently, C++ doesn't support contravariance, so this is only an academic discussion.

The overriding function in your code does not accept calls to the old interface, so it does not count as  contravariance.
Overridden:

```
virtual void foo(int bar):
```

Overriding:

```
void foo(int bar, double additionalParameter) override {/*...*/} };
```

The correct way is to follow the contravariance principles manually in C++. This is more or less what you were trying to do. You need to override:

```
void foo(int bar) override
```

And make it call the function with the additional parameter. For the user of the classes it seems like contravariance (with an additional default parameter).

Note: overloading a virtual function with a regular function is dangerous, and can cause problems. Overloading a function hides functions with similar names in the parent. This can cause confusion and bugs, unless handled with care. The `override` keyword makes the problem less severe, but still it has some risks.